# Oracle multiple "with as" issue

Tags: sql, oracle12c, common-table-expression

I'm working on Oracle 12.c Enterprise Edition (12.1.0.2.0).

I'd like to construct a randomized number of rows (here between 4 and 15 rows) - called DataSet - using 2 randomized (between 1 and 30) - called FixedSed...

... and wish that the 2 FixedSet data (val1 and val2) are constant in the DataSet.

```
with DataSet as
(
select level Ident
     , trunc(dbms_random.value(0,1)*100)-10 val
  from dual
CONNECT BY level <= dbms_random.value(4, 15)
)
, FixedSet as
(
  select trim(trunc(dbms_random.VALUE(1, 30))) val1
       , trim(trunc(dbms_random.VALUE(1, 30))) val2
    from dual
)
select *
  from DataSet, FixedSet
```

I get for example :

```
IDENT   VAL VAL1    VAL2
1       -1     6      13
2       78     6       5
3       68     7      22
4       86    19      29
5       37    15       8
6       -1     8      18
7        0     1      21
8       77    24      19
9       18    15      13
10       4    13      28
11      70     7      29
```

I wish I get something like :

```
IDENT   VAL VAL1    VAL2
1        -1    6      13
2        78    6      13
3        68    6      13
4        86    6      13
5        37    6      13
6        -1    6      13
7        0     6      13
8        77    6      13
9        18    6      13
10       4     6      13
11       70    6      13
```

The point of all of this is to return val1 when val is negative and val2 if it's positive...

What should I change ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want  constant values of `FixedSet` for every  `DataSet` row

```
with FixedSet as
(
  select level lfs, trim(trunc(dbms_random.VALUE(1, 30))) val1
       , trim(trunc(dbms_random.VALUE(1, 30))) val2
    from dual
    connect by level <=1
)
, DataSet as
(
select level Ident
     , trunc(dbms_random.value(0,1)*100)-10 val
  from dual
CONNECT BY level <= dbms_random.value(4, 15)
)
select *
  from DataSet, FixedSet;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative would be to add the val1 and val2 as part of a column definition

```
with DataSet as
(
select level Ident
     , trunc(dbms_random.value(0,1)*100)-10 val
  from dual
CONNECT BY level <= dbms_random.value(4, 15)
)
select t.*
       ,(select dbms_random.value(1,30) from dual) as val1
       ,(select dbms_random.value(1,30) from dual) as val2
  from DataSet t
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9bd7e8952ce27be660c294069d6afe21

Comment: Can feet with my first purpose. I just have to add that I also want val1 < val2... I use "with" clause to select val1 as val1 and val1+val2 as val2 in principal select... Sorry about that miss.